# How can I add a progress bar or Circular Progress this code(Flutter) while an image is loading? I have tried different solutions but no luck :(

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout

How can I add a progress bar or Circular Progress this code(Flutter) while an image is loading? I have tried different solutions but no luck :(.

How can I add a progress bar or Circular Progress this code(Flutter) while an image is loading? I have tried different solutions but no luck :(.

````
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view_gallery.dart';

class OnlineImage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OnlineImageState createState() => _OnlineImageState();
}
class _OnlineImageState extends State<OnlineImage> {
  final imageList = [
    'https://colorlinemapsapp.000webhostapp.com/wallpaper/DHA%20PESHAWAR%20UPDATE%20PLAN%20(%20A%20)-Model%20(1)_page-0001.jpg',
  ];
//images url
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        title: Text("Hayatabad Master Plan"),
      ),
      // add this body tag with container and photoview widget
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 800,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 20,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
                    itemCount: imageList.length,
                    builder: (context, index) {
                      return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
                        basePosition: Alignment.center,
                        imageProvider: NetworkImage(imageList[index]),
                        minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 0.8,
                        maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered * 5,
                      );
                    },
                    scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                    ),

                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),[enter image description here][1]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/znE6t.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xJ7b.gif
````

Answer (score 0):

Use [This](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) plugin to implement this.

**Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:**

```
dependencies:
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.1
```

**And include it as:**

```
CachedNetworkImage(
 imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
 placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
 errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
),
```

**On your Case**

````
class OnlineImage extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
    _OnlineImageState createState() => _OnlineImageState();
   } 
   class _OnlineImageState extends State<OnlineImage> {
     final imageList = [
    'https://colorlinemapsapp.000webhostapp.com/wallpaper/DHA%20PESHAWAR%20UPDATE%20PLAN%20(%20A%20)-Model%20(1)_page-0001.jpg',
  ];
//images url
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        title: Text("Hayatabad Master Plan"),
      ),
      // add this body tag with container and photoview widget
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 800,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 20,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
                    itemCount: imageList.length,
                    builder: (context, index) {
                      return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
                        basePosition: Alignment.center,
                        imageProvider:CachedNetworkImage(
 imageUrl: imageList[index],
 placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
 errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
),
                        minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 0.8,
                        maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered * 5,
                      );
                    },
                    scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                    ),

                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} ```
````

Comment: Actually, I'm new with flutter, exactly where I have to put your code in my code.

Comment: @waseemafzal Hey, check the plugin page. You wouldn't regret it! also, it contains an example

Comment: @waseemafzal See my answer i have edited it.

Comment: https://ibb.co/64MGShB , please check it out, I have some error,

Comment: Thank you guys for help

Comment: @waseemafzal cant view image

Comment: please check it here, https://pasteboard.co/JRXO7fC.png

Comment: mohan.smk23@gmail.com contact me